# How do I access webform components labels on the congratulations page

Tags: webforms

Am using the following code in the Congratulations page. There is more but this is the driving force to retrieve user submissions. Its working fine but I need to retreive as well the actual component labels. How do I include the actual questions (labels) on the form. Like if I have a component:

How old are you

- 10
- 25

How do I modify the code below to show "How old are you" on the congratulations page?

```
<?php
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') .'/includes/webform.submissions.inc');
$nid = arg(1); 
$sid = $_GET['sid'];
$submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
        echo $submission->data[$i]['value'][0];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 12):

The loaded submission doesn't hold the label names so you'll have to get them from elsewhere. One option would be to load the webform node where they can be found. Here's an example about how this would look like in the code:

```
<?php
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') .'/includes/webform.submissions.inc');
$nid = arg(1); 
$sid = $_GET['sid'];
$submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
$node = node_load($nid);
foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $key => $component) {
  if (isset($submission->data[$key]['value'][0])) {
    if ($component['type'] == 'select') {
      $options = array();
      $items = explode("\n", $component['extra']['items']);
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item_parts = explode('|', $item);
        if (isset($item_parts[0]) && isset($item_parts[1])) $options[$item_parts[0]] = $item_parts[1];
      }
      $no = count($submission->data[$key]['value']);
      if ($no > 1) {
        $cont = '<p><strong>'. $component['name'] .':</strong> ';
        foreach ($submission->data[$key]['value'] as $k => $v) {
          if ($k + 1 == $no) $cont .= $options[$v];
          else $cont .= $options[$v] .', ';
        }
        $cont .= '</p>';
        echo $cont;
      }
      elseif (isset($options[$submission->data[$key]['value'][0]])) {
        echo '<p><strong>'. $component['name'] .':</strong> '. $options[$submission->data[$key]['value'][0]] .'</p>';
      }
    }
    else {
      echo '<p><strong>'. $component['name'] .':</strong> '. $submission->data[$key]['value'][0] .'</p>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: OMG!! Cant thank you enough. I popped your codes in the congrats page and miracles happened! I dont even need my old codes anymore! Thanks a million! One more thing. What if I want to get the exact description of the chosen option value instead of option numbers?

Comment: @Albert Dealing with select options, checkboxes and radio buttons means a good chunk of extra code in this case. I updated my answer to cover those cases as well now.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked but also threw this error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in eval() (line 14 of". Line 14 contains: "$options[$item_parts[0]] = $item_parts[1];"

Comment: @Albert Replacing that line with `if (isset($item_parts[0]) && isset($item_parts[1])) $options[$item_parts[0]] = $item_parts[1];` should fix it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. I think my problem is 100% solved!

Comment: @Albert Glad to hear, hopefully no other issues pop up :)

Comment: @Albert don't forget to accept this answer as correct by clicking the tick next to it :)