# drupal webform : how to get values inside a component type fieldset

Tags: webforms

I know to retreive information contained in a textfield that is not in a fieldset by
     $submission->data[cid][value][0].
but as soon as it is in a fieldset, textfield component 
     $submission->data[cid][value][0] gives me nothing.
How do I do to retreive information contained in a textfield component contained in a fieldset component.
.

Comment: Have a look here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/how-do-i-access-webform-components-labels-on-the-congratulations-page There they fetch webform submission data and labels for the fields.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. i used foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $key => $component) {
  if (isset($submission->data[$key]['value'][0])) {
  switch ($component['name']){